# Cards in Tabler UI won't get equal in height using flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Tabler UI to put cards on my website using the `.card` inside of columns. I want to have the cards an equal height to each other.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cards">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="row row-cards row-deck">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="card text-center">
                        <div class="card-status bg-blue"></div>
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Interne punten</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="h1">0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="card text-center">
                        <div class="card-status bg-blue"></div>
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Externe punten</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="h1">0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="card text-center">
                        <div class="card-status bg-blue"></div>
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Totale punten</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="h1">0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div class="row row-cards row-deck">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-status bg-red"></div>
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Punten per interne categoriën</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table card-table table-striped table-vcenter table-hover">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>TestRow</td>
                                        <td>22.5</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-status bg-red"></div>
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Punten per externe categoriën</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table card-table table-striped table-vcenter table-hover">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>SeondTestRow</td>
                                        <td>23</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>testrow24</td>
                                        <td>3</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-outline table-vcenter text-nowrap card-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center w-1">
                                    <i class="icon-people"></i>
                                </th>
                                <th>User</th>
                                <th>Usage</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Payment</th>
                                <th>Activity</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Satisfaction</th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    <i class="icon-settings"></i>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It splits the row in 2 columns. The left column should have 2 cards next to each other (`.col-6`) and one below that which is the full length (`.col-12`).

The right column should also have 2 cards next to each other (`.col-6`) with nothing underneath. These 2 cards should have the same height, which works right now using the `.row-deck` class on the parent row.

I also want these columns (right side) to have a minimum height of the left ones. The right columns in the picture should be stretched to the "Totale punten" card.

[image]

What I tried was the `.h-100` on the `.card` element. This resulted in having no margin or padding on some of them, which made it hard to work with.

What is the best way to do this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: show any image or example how actually u want

Comment: @VinoThini The example is in the picture. The 2 cards on the right should be as tall as where the 'totale punten' ends.

Comment: Ok then you have to increase the card height of the 2 cards in the right

Comment: @VinoThini What? The left column doesn't have a fixed height value.

Comment: you better link this into github issue, not that many people use tabler UI